# Using Maps in C++ and into Java

Tags: java, c++, file, oop

I am trying to practice my java skills by using my old C++ codes and trying to convert them over. So I have this code below that uses std::map (as shown below):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    string ifile = argv[1];
    ifstream icookie {ifile};
    ofstream ocookie {"ocookie.txt",ios::out};
    string Lines;
    map<string,int>CookieMap;
    while(getline(icookie,Lines))
    {
        CookieMap[Lines]++;
    }

    for (auto it : CookieMap)
    {
        cout << it.first << " " << it.second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code is reading a file ocookie.txt that contains:

```
chocolate
snickerdoodle
vanilla
chocolate
vanilla
sugar
vanilla
```

The output then should be:

```
chocolate 2
snickerdoodle 1
vanilla 3
sugar 1
```

I am just confused on how to do the std::map like that in java for I am not sure how many lines there will be. Thank you and any help is appreciated.

Comment: *I am trying to practice my java skills* -- Do not use C++ as a model in writing Java code.  They are different languages with different idioms.  Learn Java independent of what you have used in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [how to read a file in java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/). Then, you can use the [HashMap Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to get that kind of behaviour.

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your answer is self contained, see ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

An example with JDK8+:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ocookie.txt"));

    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.compute(line, (k, v) -> {
            if (v == null) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return v + 1;
            }
        });
    }

    result.forEach( (k, v) -> {
        System.out.printf("%s %s\n", k, v);
    });
```